# Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment when login redmine

Tags: ruby, centos

I am install redmine on CentOS 7.2,Rails 4.2, ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux-gnu].when I am started server using command:

```
ruby /usr/local/bin/rails server webrick -e production –d
```

And login:http://localhost:3000. throws:

```
Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`
```

[image]
This is my secrets.yml:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 58176e0eea05......

test:
  secret_key_base: 58176e0eea05......

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: 58176e0eea05......
```

I have already tried to generate a key,What should I do to make it right?

This is the detail log:

```
[root@localhost redmine]# ruby /usr/local/bin/rails server webrick -e production –d
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-11-17 04:09:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-11-17 04:09:06] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-11-17 04:09:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2972 port=3000
http://localhost:3000[2016-11-17 04:09:25] ERROR RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
        /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
        /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        /usr/share/ruby/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Have you restarted the server after adding keys? Everything seems right.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri Already restarted,but still not ok.

Comment: Are you sure you should be posting credentials publicly on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have removed the sensitive info away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a secret key:

```
    #change to redmine directory
    cd /var/www/redmine

    #generate secret key
    rake secret RAILS_ENV=production

    export SECRET_KEY_BASE=generate key

    #check secret key
    echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

reboot.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 (after an upgrade) redmine failed. @Dolphin's answer helped. I only had to find out that the key must reside in `/var/lib/redmine/default/config/` After putting the info in place system started again.